# which is best way to replace already installed software

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have already installed a software which is developed in .net in my organization. now we required some little bit changes. i have done these changes and make a .exe file. now question is how i replace already installed software with new one. my application will run on different clients machine.

Comment: Well, how did you deploy it the first time? MSI? manual copy? ClickOnce? setup.exe? domain policy?

Comment: is the exe of that app on all clients in the same folder?

Comment: i send set up of my application to all clients.

Comment: Well, send them the new setup

Answer (score 0):

you can use two technologies in order to make a packaging that is setup software

windows installer
or 
Click once
here a comparison
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973805.aspx

Comment: how i get some configuration setting while installation of software? while running installation system required ip address and port no etc.

Comment: Hi, you can customize your setup so you can have setup page that will specify ip adress and port no.Remember that when you use a setup (msi), you often set path of program

Comment: can you please give me example link that describe how customize setup page? I am new in .net. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

here is solution ...

http://raquila.com/software/configure-app-config-application-settings-during-msi-install/